# Flask running python scripts with different html buttons

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to build a web page using Flask and Python on my Raspberry pi which has about 20 different html buttons which when clicked will play a different sound file each. So far I have created a Pygame script to play each sound through my Pi 3.5mm jack and added imported some to my Flask python script with different urls for the buttons.

My app.py Flask script is below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():

return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/move')
def b():
import movingin
return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/call')
def c():
import firstcall
return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

This is a pygame script to play the sound:

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/pi/Music/first call.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
continue
```

When I click the first button linking to /move, it plays the sound and loads the index.html again but when clicking the same button, nothing happens.

This is my index.html button code:

```
<div class="col-1-4 mobile-col-1-1">
        <div class="button"><a href="/move">Moving In</a></div>
        </div>
```

How can I get it so that no matter how many times I click each button, it will always run the imported python script linked to each button?

Thanks in advance.